# How to merge two tables and insert parenthesis on even rows

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to insert parenthesis on specific locations after merging two tables using the package **pgfplotstable**.

I have the following tables:

```
\begin{filecontents}{stats.csv}
Parameter,Stat
     ,    0.012  
     ,    0.457  
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Parameter,Value
alpha,    10.2
beta ,    15.1
\end{filecontents}
```

I want this final result:

```
Parameter   Value
___________________
alpha       10.2
            (0.012)  
beta        15.1
            (0.457)
```

The column **Value** should be aligned by the decimal separator.

Thanks for any advice!

Marcos

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read both tables with `\pgfplotstableread` and called them `\mydata` and `\mystats`.

Then I have used `\pgfplotstabletypeset`, starting from the `\mydata` table, and using `after row` option to create a new row taken from `\mystats` table.

The correct alignment is achieved with `dcolumn` package.

It works with the sample data, I hope it works with actual ones, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{4}}
\newcounter{myrow}
\setcounter{myrow}{-1}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{stats.csv}
    Parameter,Stat
    ,    0.012  
    ,    0.457  
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Parameter,Value
    alpha,    10.2
    beta ,    15.1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{stats.csv}\mystats
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\mydata

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        multicolumn names,
        display columns/0/.style={string type},
        display columns/1/.style={string type,column type={>{\arraybackslash}d}},
        after row={%
            \stepcounter{myrow}
            & \pgfplotstablegetelem{\themyrow}{Stat}\of\mystats
            (\pgfplotsretval)\\
        },
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={%
            after row={%
                \stepcounter{myrow}
                & \pgfplotstablegetelem{\themyrow}{Stat}\of\mystats
                (\pgfplotsretval)\\
                \bottomrule
            }
        }
    ]{\mydata}

\end{document}
```

[image]